# ASP.Net aspx properties persisted

Tags: asp.net

What would be the best practice to persist property values of an aspx-page?

I have done the following, is there some neater way?

```
    public string DataTable
    {
        get
        {
            return _DataTable;
        }
        set
        {
            _DataTable = value;
            ViewState["DataTable"] = value;
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DataTable = Request["dataTable"].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            DataTable = ViewState["DataTable"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Also storing DataTable in the ViewState is not a very good idea. You should review your logic to avoid this.

Comment: It's not an actual DataTable, it's a string (probably with the table name), which is why I recommended to change the name.

Answer (score 6):

You have multiple places where you can persist data,each with it's own pros and cons, and with it' own lifespan:

**ViewState** - stored individually on each page as a hidden (somewhat encrypted) item on the client. Remember that the data has to make a round trip to the client and back on each postback, so generally it's not a good ideea to store large ammounts of data

**HiddenItem** - a hidden input control. Works the same as ViewState, except it's not enrypted and you can use the values in the JS from the client

**QueryString** - same as hiddenitem, but seriously, use it only for small ammounts of data. I think some browsers have a limit on the URL length

**Session** - has the advantage of being able to store larger ammounts of data, as this is stored on the server end, not on the client. You can get into trouble if the client is using the back/next buttons on the browser, and you need to be carefull about maintaining session data accross server farms(ie. multiple servers running the same webapp)

**Cache** - almost identical to Session, except you can access it from other sessions. This is better to use for "globally" accesable data (ie. stuff everyone uses in you app)

**Static Properties** - works the same as cache, but you cannot share it across webfarms, so each member of the webfarm will have it's own static value in it's loaded assembly.

Comment: Very nicely summarized.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            TableName = Request.QueryString["tableName"];
    }

    public string TableName
    {
        get { return ViewState["tableName"] as string; }
        set { ViewState["tableName"] = value; }
    }
```

I don't like using Request["tableName"] alone since it has to search in more places. Usually I know where I'm sending the parameter.

Also DataTable is a type, so it's best to not use it as a property name.